# All the polar ticks in a ListPolarPlot are not showing

Tags: plotting

I want to have a plot with polar axes, but the axes numbers get alway lost or I can't see them in their full size. The problem is particularly bad at the left and right edges. Also, it seems that the `PlotRange` option doesn't work. Maybe someone has an idea how I can solve the problem. I would be very happy about help.

```
ListPolarPlot[list, 
  PolarPolarAxes -> Automatic, PolarGridLines -> Automatic, 
  PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", All}, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question, and add the code from the image and other code needed to reproduce the plot. Posting the code makes it easier for us to try it by copying and pasting it rather than typing it from scratch.

Comment: Try the `ImagePadding -> All` option which might help.

Comment: @creidhne ImagePadding -> All does not work. :(

Answer (score 2):

The `ImagePadding` option will fix this problem. Its value depends on the plot and labels you use. In this case, `ImagePadding -> Scaled[.05]` displays the numbers.

```
list = Table[{r,Cos[2r]},{r,0,2\[Pi],\[Pi]/24}];
ListPolarPlot[list, PolarAxes -> Automatic, PolarGridLines -> Automatic,
  PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", All}, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> All,
  ImagePadding -> Scaled[.05]]
```

Comment: `PlotRangePadding` is a better solution. See m_goldberg's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Plot range padding also works. Like so:

```
ListPolarPlot[Table[Sin[2 i], {i, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/100}],
  PolarAxes -> True,
  PolarGridLines -> Automatic,
  PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic},
  PlotStyle -> Blue,
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.12]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: But the numbers are also cut off in this picture. At least in the range 105  to 210.
Dont you see it? :(

Comment: @Nick Yes, I made mistake. I have revised my answer.

Comment: Thank you!  It works!